# Raspberry Pi is always Read-Only after installing

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, sd-card, mount, readwrite

Model: Raspberry Pi 3 B

SD: 8GB MicroSDHC

For the past couple of weeks I've been stuck with my Pi not working. I've followed numerous guides. I've downloaded Raspbian Stretch With Desktop OS from the official site, Written the image with both EtcherIO and Win32DiskImager to the SD card, Set the IP and ssh file in the SD card, and then connected to it with Putty, everything alright so far. 
Now on the Pi itself, no matter how many times I repeat this process it keeps telling me that the PI is Read-Only. I've tried using sudo, and even logging as Root, and it's still Read-Only.
[image]
[image]

I've found that raspi-config gives an error that there's nothing mounted, tried mounting with "mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot", and then atleast I can access raspi-config but can still not edit anything with Nano.
Looking through Google I also noticed that my /etc/fstab file is completely empty, and should be filled with something else.
[image]

Is this a problem with the SD card, the Pi itself or am I doing something wrong that I haven't noticed at all, because I'm completely done with this right now, I cannnot figure out why I'm having this problem.

Comment: Can you post the exact contents of the `cmdline.txt` file in the `/boot` partition on the card?

Comment: `dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=ffe2f1bd-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles ip=169.254.0.180`  -I've only added the ip-line, and changed nothing else.

Comment: You probably shouldn't set the link-local IP address in the cmdline... if you remove that option, you can find out the link-local address by simply pinging the Pi... `ping raspberrypi.local` from your host PC...  It seems like the filesystems on the card are not being mounted properly at boot.  However, you can check to be sure that the partitions are setup properly by issuing this command on the Pi :  `lsblk -o NAME,PARTUUID,FSTYPE,SIZE` ... make sure that the PARTUUID for the `ext4` partition matches the one listed in the `cmdline.txt`  ... Have you tried a different SD card?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NWzQ.png this is what I got, I don't really see anything wrong here I think.

Comment: I only have the one SD card, which is why I wouldve preferred if I could solve this, but I did just buy a 16gb Sandisk MicroSD, hoping that this fixes the problem. :V

Comment: The numbering matches... However, for some strange reason the `/boot` partition is not mounted... probably because `/etc/fstab` is missing...  Does the `shasum` of the downloaded zip file  match what is displayed on the Raspbian download page?

Comment: Note that not having the `/boot` partition doesn't matter, it isn't used for anything (except for you tweaking the config, and the distro updating the kernel etc.).

Answer (score 4):

Since it seems that your `/etc/fstab` is missing, you may want to fill it in with the necessary information.  You'll need to manually mount the root  and boot partitions first:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/mmcblk0p2 /
```

And then create a new `/etc/fstab`

```
sudo echo -e "proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0\n/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2\n/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1" > /etc/fstab
```

And the to verify that the above command worked:

```
$cat /etc/fstab

proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```

And then change the root partition in your `cmdline.txt` to `/dev/mmcblk0p2` You can do this on your Windows machine, just like you did to add the IP.

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
```

Comment: You should perhaps use `mount -o remount,rw ` since at least the root fs partition must already be mounted.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect `remount` option.

Comment: Following these steps at the very least gives me the ability to edit files again, but the /etc/fstab does not get saved, and I have to do it again every time I restart the PI, while other files DO get saved. Is there any solution to this? ... I keep getting the "Structure needs cleaning" message when I try to save it, and that apparently does link to file corruption.

Comment: So, i'm pretty sure that the problem HAS to lie on the SD-card's end, because this is just too much trouble for even getting the basics to work. Regardless, I've tried searching for errors with `e2fsck` which gives me the message that mmcblk0p2 is still busy so it can't do it, but `sudo umount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /`  just gives `umount: /: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)`

Comment: @Sven0567 : If you want to run fsck, you can place an empty file called `forcefsck` in the root directory...  `sudo touch /forcefsck`  This will enable fsck at next boot and also remove the `/forcefsck` file at the same time...  My guess is either the image file was somehow corrupted upon download from the web or the SD card is flaky.

Comment: Well, startup after fsck takes a loooong time, so I'm just guessing it'll be lost if I can't connect in a while.

Comment: @Sven0567 : an fsck running on my Pi Zero completed in less than 30 seconds on a 16GB card.  So, I'm guessing there are either a lot of errors on the card or something is horribly wrong with the image file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by re-formatting the SD card using disk utility for MacOS, and then re-mounting the OS image (raspbian in my case) to the drive. I made sure to use MS-DOS format and GUID partition map:

[image]